# BiBLaTeX won't recognize bib file

Tags: biblatex, biber, scrbook

This seems like an extremely simple issue but I just can't figure out what's going wrong. I have a minimal bib file called References:

```
@book{Chushakushi,
    author      = {Ii Haruki},
    title       = {Genji monogatari ch\=ushakushi},
    publisher   = {Something},
    year        = {1980}
}
```

Then I am using LuaLaTeX+MakeIndex+BiBText to compile the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

Hi there This book\footcite{Chushakushi} is my reference

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This was working fine with natbib but with biblatex it gives me:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Chushakushi' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 13.
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: Test and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

It seems to me like this has to be something really stupid and simple but I just can't figure it out. If I take out "backend=biber" the same thing happens. I have tried compiling it several times in a row and nothing changes. Replacing \addbibresource with \bibliography also does nothing.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: as it is, you need to use `biber` (not `bibtex`) run biber to generate the bibliography, then re-run latex

Comment: Your compilation run isn't complete. You need `LuaLaTeX+MakeIndex+Biber+LuaLaTeX+LuaLaTeX`

Comment: Thank you both; I was able to use this answer with helpful pictures to configure MiKTeX 2.9 to use Biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations